# Static tableview tap to top on iOS only works on some controllers?

Tags: ios, controller, scroll, tableview

I have designed an app (not yet released) in which two tableview controllers have static cells. When you tap the status bar, it should zoom to the top. However, only one of them does this. What could cause the interference on the one not working?

Comment: in the controller that does not scroll to top there is some other element that intercept scroll events?

Comment: No. They are actually almost identical (the one that doesn't work has 2 less static cells). Any suggestions?

Comment: debugging issues like this is a pain.  I would start by setting a breakpoint where you detect the tap on the status bar and drill down line by line.  Make sure the scroll view isn't nil and has the proper delegates to handle the scrolling.  Also make sure the tabelview nibs are hooked up to their corresponding tableview controller files.

Comment: Ok. So there is a slight difference thanks to your suggestion. The tableview is hooked up in the .h file for the one not working (which I do need), while the one that is working is not hooked up to the .h. I have set a self.delegate, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I actually am detecting a tap with nsnotification (response in log), but nothing happens. I have even put in                                                       [self.tableView setScrollsToTop:YES];, but it simply will not scroll up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that since I had hooked it up, I had to manually detect when a user tapped the clock and then scroll it programmatically to the top

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"_UIApplicationSystemGestureStateChangedNotification"
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                      NSLog(@"Status bar pressed!");
                                                      //[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
                                                      [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];


                                                  }];
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine in iOS 6 but in iOS 7,the method works in full view i.e if we tap on table view or select any row of table view then table view scrolls to top.Please suggest